# should I set strong IBOutlet to nil when receive memory warning under ARC?

Tags: iphone, ios

In ios6 should I set strong `IBOutlet` to `nil` when receive memory warning? what about a view I declared as instance variables and added to the view hierarchy by code?

Answer (score 4):

Since iOS6, Apple recommends not releasing views, just cached data that you can recover easily, such as downloaded images. This is why they deprecated `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: But the view added by code is not resleaed after recieve memory warning.

Comment: It shouldn't be. Apple releases its view caches internally, and you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

On top of Leo Natan's answer, it also wouldn't do you any good to just set the outlet to `nil`, as you would also need to remove the outlet from its superview. Before that you would need to check that the `view` property isn't visible (has no `window` property) as well as clearing out the `view`. It's complicated and unnecessary.